# Properties of the quotient modulus annihilator

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $N,P\leq M$. it is called the quotient of $N$ by $P$ to the subset
$$(N:P):=\lbrace{a\in A\mid P\cdot a\subseteq N\rbrace}$$
Show that  $(N:P)$ it is a bilaterian ideal  of $A$. Also prove that $(0:M)=\operatorname{Ann}(M)$ and  $(N:P)=\operatorname{Ann}((N+P)/N)$

**Attempt:** To prove that $(N: P)$ is a bilaterian ideal, I have to
let $a,b\in (N:P)$, then $P.a\subseteq N$ and  $P.b\subseteq N$, therefore for all $p\in P$, we have that  $p.a\in N$ y $p.b\in N$, since that  $N$ is a sumbmodule of $M$, then $$p.a-p.b\in N$$ and by the axioms of modules then $p(a-b)\in N$, so $P.(a-b)\subseteq N$, which shows that $ (N: P) $ is a subgroup of $ M $.

Let  $a\in (N:P)$ y $b\in A$, then $P.a\subseteq N$, In fact, for all $ p \in P $ we have $ p.a \in N $, since $ P \leq M $ then:
$$(p.a).b=p.(ab)\in N$$
therefore $ P. (ab) \subseteq N $ that is $ (N: P) .b \subseteq N $. In other words, it is a left ideal, analogously it is a right ideal.

it is trivial that $(0:M)=\operatorname{Ann}(M)$

I would like to know if I am using the definition correctly to prove that it is a bilaterian ideal.

**I don't know how to show that $(N:P)=\operatorname{Ann}((N+P)/N)$, any suggestion is welcome.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a small correction for the first part: it should be $(N:P).b \subseteq (N:P)$ instead of $(N:P).b \subseteq N$.

For the second part, as $(N+P)/N = \{p+N : p \in P\}$, note that $\operatorname{Ann}((N+P)/N)$ consist of all those elements $a \in A$ for which $(p+N).a = N$ for all $p \in P$, but $$(p+N).a = N \iff p.a+N = N \iff p.a \in N.$$

Comment: excuse me @azif00, $(N+P)/N=\lbrace (n+p)+N:n\in N\quad ,p\in P\rbrace$?

Comment: Yes, and $(n+p)+N = p+N$ since $(n+p)-p = n \in N$.

Comment: Thank you very much @azif00